# supported .net frameworks on windows server 2012 r2

Tags: windows-server-2012, dotnet-framework

is it possible to install .net frameworks 1.0, 1.1, 2.0 on windows server 2012 r2?

we need a build slave running legacy builds on visual studio 2003/2005 compilers and we'd like to have a single machine running on new and old frameworks instead of duplicating the infrastracture on two systems... to make things even more interesting - we need to install frameworks from command line / powershell for automatic deployment of the slave...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.0 and 1.1 aren't supported at all on 2012 R2.  2.0 is included in the 3.51 framework.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925570%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

> It is not possible to manually install the .NET Framework 1.1 on
>   Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012, or Windows Server 2012
>   R2. It is no longer supported. If you try to install the package, the
>   following error message is displayed: "Setup cannot continue because
>   this version of the .NET Framework is incompatible with a previously
>   installed one." To solve this problem, install the .NET Framework 3.5
>   SP1. This version includes the .NET Framework 2.0 (the release that
>   follows the .NET Framework 1.1), which is supported on Windows 8 and
>   Windows 8.1. You should always try to install the application first to
>   determine if it will automatically be updated to a later version of
>   the .NET Framework. If it does not, contact your ISV for an
>   application update.

Comment: In fact, 1.0 and 1.1 aren't supported at all anymore.  Extended support for 1.0 ended 14 July 2009, and for 1.1 it ended 8 October 2013.  Both are superseded by 2.0, which itself has been superseded by 3.0 and 3.5

Comment: thanks, this is consistent with my findings... I just wanted to make sure that there is no workaround

Comment: @Efekt  Nope, there sure isn't  You're just gonna have to keep the old server around until you manage to deprecate/port/migrate off the old codebase.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to run an older .NET exe, Win8 and Sever2012 give a popup that it needs to install support for .NET 2.0 -> .NET 3.5 (these all .NET generate code to run on CLR v2, thus the range).

As an experiment I believe I made a .NET 1.1 "Hello World".  I don't have VS2003, to target an app to .NET 1.x.  Instead, to do this I used IL to do a round-trip : 
  ildasm / text hello.exe > hello.il
  ilasm hello.il /exe /out hello_1_1.exe /MDV=1.0.3705

The original .NET 4 HelloWorld.exe just runs.  I do the change above, it causes the popup to appear.  I let MS install the .NET 2-3 support, and the .NET 1.1 test just runs.  It seems happy to run on with the v2 CLR.  (Maybe I delude myself, since I ran ilasm on a .NET 4 PC).

The .NET loader opens the exe to get the .NET version from the Metadata version string (MDV).  It tries to find:
HKLM\Software\Microsoft.NetFramework\Policy\Standards\v1.0.3705.  When this is not found, it examines a sister key \Upgrades, where it finds it can map v1.0.0-2.0.50727 to .NET 2.0.50727.

This might fail with apps more complicated than "Hello World".  Also this would not trick the installer, so it applies only to install-by-xcopy apps.  Also MS will continue to not support 1.x (and pretty soon 2.x).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install .net 1.1 on Server 2012 R2.  I downloaded the installation package to another system, moved it to the server, started the install, was able to click through compatibility warnings, and the install completed. I haven't yet figured out what factor would prevent the install, but I have, like others, run into an issue where I could not install .net 1.1 on server 2012 R2.  I am doing this install as a local admin.

Answer (score 0):

This explains how:

http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/how-to-install-aspnet-11-with-iis-on-vista-and-windows-2008

Basically you can enable IIS6 compatibility, install the framework and service packs. then add the isapi extension to IIS (or just "allow" it since the setup should install it).

Comment: this explains how to do it on vista and windows 2008 - have you actually tried it on 2012 r2?

Answer (score -3):

It is POSSIBLE to manually install the .NET Framework 1.1 on Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012, or Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: A hint on how to do this would go long way towards providing a more useful answer.